# path_to_check in shell prompt

Tags: rvm, octopress

I am using oh-my-zsh and RVM and generally I was pretty happy until I discovered [Octopress](http://octopress.org/). Picture first:
[image]

I have a custom shell prompt that displays current dir, git status, git branch, etc. It seems that Octopress code somehow breaks RVM. Or, at least, I found traces of `path_to_check` in [this file in RVM repo](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/rvmrc).

My `.rvmrc` contains this string

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

But if I empty the file, or delete it altogether, it makes no difference. It's the first time I'm seeing this and I definitely suspect that Octopress is involved.

Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was some temporary malfunction in a oh-my-zsh theme. When I started trying out other themes, they were functioning normally. And, in the end, my theme started working again too. I don't know what was the reason, or how it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try after this commit https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/fde2352fd88ebfd82d6021663f34c81f0f020dc0 it has to be related to my last changes ... but I can not see any reason except this fix.

Anyway talk to me on irc channel #rvm on freenode servers if it still gives you problems.